# Algorithm to find location of a word in a video?

Tags: algorithm

I have bunch of videos and their transcripts. Using the transcripts I need to find the position of the word in the video. It doesnt have to be the exact position but as close as possible.

So far I have thought about using the number of words spoken by an average speaker to find the relative position.

I was wondering if there is a better way to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: I would take the total time of the video and divide by the number of words in the transcript. Of course, no method will be very accurate, because some portions of the video will not have dialog.  A workaround would be to have someone watch the video with a clicker, and click every time they hear a word.

Comment: Are you really looking for the "optimal" algorithm? Or are you just looking for something that works?

Comment: Looking for something that works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer :* Because this is a general question on algorithms without mention of any technologies or stacks I am going to take liberty of being ambitious and assume you can actually do stuff I am proposing :)

1. Use speech detection on Video. Even rough translations would do because you have actual transcripts. Plenty speech to text libraries are available.
2. Then do approximation string match of the translated script with the transcript you already have
3. Identify the time stamps for above matches
4. Assign real transcripts to those time stamps

I don't think the averaging approach you are taking can be very accurate because of things like speech speed, semantics, accents, grammar etc.. Your best bet is to use a library to translate and match the rough with authoritative scripts.

Ofcourse the matching and assigning timestamps will take a lot of refining and some level of fuzzy logic, but its a start!